# Why does a dot occurs in joints of lines drawn using core graphics in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am using the below code to draw a polygon. The image I get is below:

[image]

The code I am using for drawing the square is below:

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[topLeftBoxBorderColor set];
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 1.0f);
CGContextSetLineJoin(currentContext,kCGLineJoinMiter);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, originXOfSubviews, originYOfSubviews);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, originXOfSubviews+widthOfBox, originYOfSubviews);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, originXOfSubviews+widthOfBox, originYOfSubviews+heightOfBox);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, originXOfSubviews, originYOfSubviews+heightOfBox);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, originXOfSubviews, originYOfSubviews);
CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
```

There is a white dot at the junction of two lines in all corners. Is there any way to avoid having this dot?

**UPDATE 1:**

I know the below solution: Based on the line width the , starting point of the line can be changed and achieved what I expect. But is there any other solution?

UPDATE 2:

I am using the below code to draw the polygon

When ever I set the lineWidth to 1 or less than that, the same problem happens. If I set it to 2 or above the problem does not arise.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, topLeftBoxBorderColor.CGColor);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(originXOfSubviews,originYOfSubviews,widthOfBox,heightOfBox);

    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: do you use a color with transparency?

Comment: I dont See an additional white dot, i See that the junctions are overlapping, which would cause that effect when there are transparancy effects somehow involved. At that POS there is nö additional Point, there is a Point with wrong color.

Comment: THanks for the correction. It was an overlap.

Comment: but this overlap would only be visible when there is somehow transparency involved. (full white is full white)

Answer (score 2):

It is the intersection of both the lines (Horizontal and Vertical).

What you can do is make this line few pixels/points lesser than the total lenght that you are using now. It wont intersect and no dot will come.

EDIT:

Or you can draw square,instead of drawling lines

```
- (void)drawSquare:(CGRect)rect{
    //Get the CGContext from this view
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Draw a rectangle
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    //Define a rectangle
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    //Draw it
    CGContextFillPath(context); 
}
```

Comment: I do not want them to be filled.